# Component's @Input suddenly produces errors

Tags: javascript, angular, components, dropdown, ng-bootstrap

So i have this ultra weird scenario...

I left my application working perfectly fine a week ago and got back to work on it today, realizing the dropdown i have doesn't work anymore...

I have the super simple Component:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Card} from "../../entities/Card";

@Component({
    selector: 'card-details',
    templateUrl: './app/components/card-details/CardDetails.html',
})
export class CardDetailsComponent {
    @Input() card: Card;

    constructor() {}
}
```

HTML:

```
<template #cardDetails>
    <label>{{card.cardNumber}}</label>
    <br/>
    <label>{{card.cardNetwork}}</label>
    <br/>
    <label>{{card.type}}</label>
</template>
<button class="dropdown-item" placement="right" [ngbTooltip]="cardDetails">
    {{card.cardName}}
</button>
```

And the Parent Component's relevant html code:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu" ngbDropdownToggle>Choose a card..</button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <card-details *ngFor="let card of cards; let i = index" [card]="card" (click)="selectCard(i)"></card-details>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I'm receiving an error saying it couldn't read the card's properties, `cannot read property cardName of undefined`.

Feels like i have to mention it again, I changed literally -nothing- in my code, the dropdown worked perfectly fine displaying all the details, just ran it again after a week.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for all the help, let me know if something is missing

## EDIT

Might be worth noting that placing a`console.log(JSON.stringify(this.card)` on the `ngOnInit` it has the card filled with the data. So it is filled with the correct data from the DB but still produces this error.

## Edit2

Moreover, inspecting the HTML Elements I can see that there are exactly two `card-details` containing their correct names... so what is the problem here? :O

## UPDATE

Again, cannot find any logic in that -> i initialized it with a:

```
let defaultCard: Card = new Card();
defaultCard.cardName = "default";
defaultCard.cardNetwork = "whatever";
defaultCard.cardNumber = 1564987;
defaultCard.type = "Debit";
```

and now the logs within the `ctor` and `ngOnInit` :

```
ctor
{"cardName":"default","cardNetwork":"whatever","cardNumber":1564987,"type":"Debit"}
ctor
{"cardName":"default","cardNetwork":"whatever","cardNumber":1564987,"type":"Debit"}
init
{"cardNumber":208461269,"cardName":"Magic Card","cardNetwork":"American Express","type":"Credit"}
init
{"cardNumber":220319960,"cardName":"Men Card","cardNetwork":"Visa","type":"Debit"}
```

Please, any insights would help me a lot!

Comment: I would really like to know why is this being downvoted?

Comment: What does the Card entity look like?

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski simple contains the displayed properties `cardName` `cardNetwork` `cardNumber` `cardType`

Comment: Obviously the `card` you are passing as input is undefined, therefore the property cannot be read. You have to take a step back and check the object you are passing.

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski Hello again, the `card` im passing isn't undefined, check my edit

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through the `cards` list. If you didn't change anything in your code and it suddenly starts to fail - something probably changed your data. Check your database? or where you read your cards from - they're probably reading empty cards.

Make sure where the error originates from where you think it does. Debugging the code that we can not see will help you pinpoint the error.

Comment: Hello Per, I'm still struggling with this problem, please look at my NEW update section, this is very strange..

Comment: @KesemDavid Are you sure the error originates from that button text? Can you trace the line number of subsitute the button text with `{{ card | json }}` to see if that is really where you get the error from?

Comment: Thank you Per, you've led me to the solution, the problem was not even in that component, it was on another component that is related to those cards... reading the errors slowly looking for the lines i found the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you try referencing `card?.cardName` instead? The component might be getting undefined for a fraction of a second. If that works (or not) it might points us in the right direction?

Comment: Hey Amit, unfortunately it produces the same results. Please take a look at my edits

Comment: Hello again Amit, I'm still struggling with this problem, please look at my NEW update section, this is very strange..

Comment: Still thinking... :)

Comment: Can you try reproducing in a plunkr?